# Entropy of flow and time-1 map

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, entropy, flows

Let $\Phi=(\phi_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ be a continuous flow on a compact metric space $X$. Let $\mu$ be a $\phi_1$-invariant measure. Then it is not hard to verify tht $\int_{0}^{1} \phi_t\mu dt$ is $\Phi$-invariant measure. I would like to whether it is possible to compare the value of entropies $h(\mu)$ and $h(\int_{0}^{1} \phi_t\mu dt)$. Are they equal? Thanks.